# GRUB Menu scrolling

Tags: grub2

I am looking to find a way to add a wraparound function to the GRUB menu, so that if a user presses the down key and reaches the bottom of the list, it will return to the top of the list.

Context for this... This is on a fully rugged military tablet that only has Down Arrow & Right Arrow physical buttons. Since there is no up arrow, if they reach the bottom of the list and passed their selection, they would have to reboot and try again.

Thanks!

Comment: Very interesting question. Not sure what's the answer, but I suggest taking a look at the [GNU GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#sendkey). You will probably be using the sendkey command as an interface.

Comment: Thanks! I will start looking into that to see. I'm probably already way out of my league as far as ability wise, so I was hoping there might already be a guide on how to do something like this.

Comment: I'm not an expert either. Just an enthusiast, but my guess is that you'd end up with a custom grub, which either will become deprecated down the line with future updates or you could try to push it into the Linux mainline or your Distro, meaning that it will be maintained in the future.

Comment: Something odd. I had to rebuild the system and I've reinstalled everything. I can no longer find sendkey as an option in GRUB. Any ideas?